# Ubuntu Server Xenial - Failing to boot randomly

Tags: boot, server, grub2, kernel

I recently got a new server PC. I thought Ubuntu would be a good operating system for it.
First thing I noticed that the latest LTS didn't boot. I ignored this and just used an older version 13.04.

I started upgrading it until it reached Xenial and now, the default Linux kernel (4.4.0-148) provided by GRUB always fails to boot (not completely confirmed). GRUB however finishes.

After that I used an older Linux kernel from the advanced options page (3.1.3.0-170) it booted and I thought everything was fine.

After I rebooted however, the computer didn't boot to the older Linux kernel and got stuck after the GRUB logs (I added an extra Echo command to the script to check if it got past loading the ramfs, which it did.)

Rebooting again it succeeded but with an odd resolution.

Rebooting again it stopped at a blank screen.

Rebooting again it succeeded with the correct resolution but it took long to boot, I had left it for a few minutes and it just suddenly started.

Rebooting again it stopped at a blank screen.

Rebooted to 4.4.0-148 a few times just to make sure, which all failed.

There's however one extra thing in the blank screen, some odd colored pixels at the top row, which I'm not sure if are relevant, but they're there. I'll try to provide a picture if requested.

TL;DR;

4.4.0-148 doesn't boot

3.1.3.0-170 **sometimes** boots

Am I stuck in server hell, or is there actually a reasonable solution to this? Non-reasonable, but permanent, solutions also accepted.

Server PC specs:

```
SuperMicro H8DGI-F
2x Opteron 6378
16GB DDR3-1333
```

Comment: Did you verify the ISO's before you tried using them? (ie. verify download and/or verify write-to-install-media)  Which versions did you try?  (I'm assuming a server release, but specifics may provide a clue!)  Have you run ramtests & verified the hardware is okay?  What does "didn't boot" mean?  no messages at all?  did you try booting to runlevel 1? maintenance/recovery mode? as you provide few clues beyond "didn't boot" which points to hardware or download/media-check steps skipped.

Comment: Odd resolution doesn't make sense to me for a server; as it's text mode.  If you're trying to install a desktop release, did you ensure the video card meets minimum requirements for desktop Ubuntu (most servers don't, as they are used headless or only basic gui with almost no video ram which the Ubuntu unity/gnome desktop requires!)  Odd resolution being not 25x80 lines text? or are you trying to boot gnome/unity on a server (which rarely works due to server's not meeting minimal video specs - did you check?)

Comment: Yes. 18.04.2 and 13.04. Yes, everything seemed to be fine. "Didn't boot" means that it hanged totally after GRUB was done, absolutely no message after GRUB logs. I don't know how to boot to runlevel 1. I haven't tried recovery mode yet. I don't have a dedicated video card on the server so I use the integrated Matrix G200eW graphics, which used to produce small characters but this once produced large ones, and the next successful reboot produced small ones again.

Comment: What release of 18.04.2?   There are more options than i have fingers?  Server, alternate server?  netboot? desktop? etc (given you mention server I assume it's one of the server releases, but which one).  If a desktop release, the specs state *3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB* [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Ubuntu_Desktop_Edition ]  which precludes most servers as they don't have that much memory (64mb, no 3d acceleration) given they are usually used. headless.

Comment: Server one, not net installer. Both of them.

Comment: I'll see if a proper dedicated graphics card helps at all.

Comment: Alright, I tried to reboot the latest kernel with HD 3870. It booted, and I rebooted a few times to make sure. Then I noticed that it was picking the signal from the onboard video chip. So, it suddenly became consistent (so far, 4 times) after inserting the video card. But the video didn't come from the graphics card itself. I tried removing the graphics card, but now it won't boot. I added the graphics card back and the boot froze on a message "cannot find any crtc or sizes - going to 1024x768. It was on the "smaller resolution" again. After which I rebooted and it booted fine.

Comment: I'll keep rebooting it a few times to make sure it's working correctly.

Comment: Alright, rebooted a few times and it so far seems consistent and boots without the "smaller resolution" thing. The reason I have to use video is so that I can set up networking. Ubuntu for some reason doesn't setup my network devices and I have to edit in "ifconfig p13p1 up" into a startup script somewhere. I added it in now. Now I need to find a way to remove the gpu because I don't need video.

Comment: Alright, it starts up with nomodeset added to the GRUB script. I edited it to make it permanent and everything seems to work just fine now. Thanks!